# How to Remove Specific Letters from each word in a String - PHP

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have this string:

> Hello World Hello My World

I want to remove first 3 characters in the entire string (but only if the word starts with 'Hel'). Output should be:

> lo World lo My World

Can anyone recommend a solution for this?

Comment: So what have you tried, there are many solutions... non of them are rocket science

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$str = "Hello World Hello My World";
print_r(preg_replace("/\bHel/", "", $str));  // "lo World lo My World"
```

Additional approach for the condition *to remove "rld" from each word (only if it appears at the end of the word)*:

```
print_r(preg_replace("/rld\b/", "", $str));  // Hello Wo Hello My Wo
```

Comment: How about if i want to remove "rld" from each word (only if it appears at the end of the word)? // To get output like "Hello Wo Hello My Wo"

Comment: @ChintanJain, see my update

Comment: @chris85, yes, I just remembered that it should only start with "Hel"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$str = "Hello World Hello My World";
$arr = explode(" ",$str);
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($arr); $i++)
    {
      if (substr( $arr[$i], 0, 3 ) === "Hel")
      {
       $arr[$i] = str_replace("Hel","",$arr[$i]);
      }
    }
$outputstr = implode(" ",$arr);
```

What this does is that it slices the string into array of different words and then in the loop I am replacing the Hel with nothing so this will remove the Hel and them imploding the array back into the String... This will check if Hel is in the start and then will replace...

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Ok, lemme work on that too

Comment: Done that too bro... :) @chris85

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use the `str_replace` function.

**Example**

```
$output = str_replace(' Hel', ' ', $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @chris85 my bad, changed

Comment: Half way there, still won't require the word start with `Hel` though. For example pass in `CHello`.